# Error in Fetching data from MongoDb while connection established in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I got connected with monogdb via pyspark python. I am able to printSchema as well but Whenever I want to show records then getting error. Here is my code

```python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext, functions as F

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import findspark
findspark.init()

import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
# create a spark session
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("ABC") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/demo") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/demo") \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector:10.0.2') \
    .config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000) \
    .getOrCreate()
# read data from mongodb collection "questions" into a dataframe "df"
df = spark.read \
    .format("mongodb") \
    .option("uri", "mongodb://localhost:2701/demo.rides_active") \
    .option("database", "demo") \
    .option("collection", "rides_active") \
    .load()

df.show()
# df.printSchema()
```

Error I am getting:

```
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/C:/SPARK/jars/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: C:\Users\Lenovo\.ivy2\cache
The jars for the packages stored in: C:\Users\Lenovo\.ivy2\jars
org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-e4701641-da31-46ad-8a99-7186d0cb5f29;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector;10.0.2 in central
    found org.mongodb#mongodb-driver-sync;4.5.1 in central
    [4.5.1] org.mongodb#mongodb-driver-sync;[4.5.0,4.5.99)
    found org.mongodb#bson;4.5.1 in central
    found org.mongodb#mongodb-driver-core;4.5.1 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 2536ms :: artifacts dl 8ms
    :: modules in use:
    org.mongodb#bson;4.5.1 from central in [default]
    org.mongodb#mongodb-driver-core;4.5.1 from central in [default]
    org.mongodb#mongodb-driver-sync;4.5.1 from central in [default]
    org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector;10.0.2 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   4   |   1   |   0   |   0   ||   4   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-e4701641-da31-46ad-8a99-7186d0cb5f29
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 4 already retrieved (0kB/6ms)
23/12/17 11:13:29 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProject\pythonProject\PySpark\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    df.show(5)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 959, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.showString.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.schema.RowToInternalRowFunction.<init>(RowToInternalRowFunction.java:46)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.schema.BsonDocumentToRowConverter.<init>(BsonDocumentToRowConverter.java:104)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.MongoBatch.<init>(MongoBatch.java:43)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.MongoScan.toBatch(MongoScan.java:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.BatchScanExec.batch$lzycompute(BatchScanExec.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.BatchScanExec.batch(BatchScanExec.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.BatchScanExec.inputPartitions$lzycompute(BatchScanExec.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.BatchScanExec.inputPartitions(BatchScanExec.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.supportsColumnar(DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.supportsColumnar$(DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.BatchScanExec.supportsColumnar(BatchScanExec.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Strategy.apply(DataSourceV2Strategy.scala:147)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

```
Python Version = 3.11
Pyspark Version = 3.5
PyMongo Version = 3.4.0
Java Version = 17.0.9
```

Comment: _`.option("uri", "mongodb://localhost:2701/demo.rides_active")`_ `2701`?